# recursive sed search for text between two strings. Output the text and the filepath to screen

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a command which will output the text between the user defined strings but I cannot seem to output the filename the text originates from...

Is there a way to adapt the current command to do this?

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -n '/'$1'/,/'$2'/p' $3
```

Command syntax:

```
./shell.sh Start End *.xml
```

The ideal output would be something like:

> filename
>
> text between $1 and $2
>
> Next filename
>
> text between $1 and $2
>
> and so on...

Comment: What's the meaning of `$3`? It is a file mask, but then the file names output by `find` are appended to the command, too...

Comment: I think it's almost what you want `find . -type f -print -exec sed -n "/$1/,/$2/p" '{}' \;`, though I don't know where `*.xml` take part. PLease clarify.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?  There are tricks to get the filename prepended `filename:data on the line`, like `grep . /dev/null` in the `xargs` command (and then place the `sed` after it).

Comment: Ideally I would like the output to be something like 

[filename]

the text between $1 and $2

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like

```
find . -name "$3" -type f -exec sed -n "/$1/,/$2/s%^%{}%p" {} \;
```

This can be adapted to use `xargs` but since you want the file name in the `sed` command for each file, it makes sense to run it with `find -exec` anyway.

The original place you had for `$3` did not seem correct.  I'm guessing what you want, but the above hopefully makes sense.

So `sed` ends up running something like

```
 sed -n "/foo/,/bar/s%^%/path/to/file:%p" /path/to/file
```

which will prefix the matching lines by substituting `^` (start of line) with the file name and a colon.